# Rewrite the request, keeping the params and setting a new one

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the request to the index page, keeping the query string params and adding a new one.

Exemple:

```
Request: products/?limit=10&page=4&as=many&params=as&I=need
Rewrite to: index.php?page=pages&limit=10&page=4&as=many&params=as&I=need

// index.php
$_REQUEST = array(
    'page' => 'products'
    'limit' => '10',
    'page' => '4',
    'as' => 'many'
    'params' => 'as',
    'I' => 'need'
);
```

I identify the request, set a param and rewrite to the correct page. I cannot keep the old query string params though.

```
RewriteRule ^products(.*) index.php?page=products [NC,L]
// index.php
$_REQUEST = array(
    'page' => 'products'
);
```

TIA

Comment: How is this a `mod_rewrite` based question? and is `RewriteRule ^products(.*) index.php?page=products [NC,L]` in your PHP file?

Comment: The [QSA] flag appends any substitution parameters to the existing set -- e.g. in your second example use `[NC,QSA,L]`

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey I'm sorry, I didn't make it clear. That is in my .htaccess. The php code is only to illustrate the params I get.

Comment: @terryE Thank you very much, you solved the problem. All I needed was a QSA flag.

Comment: I cannot mark this question as solved. The green check symbol is gone! :-O

Comment: You can only mark answers as the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `[QSA]` flag appends any substitution parameters to the existing set -- e.g. in your second example use `[NC,QSA,L]`.

If that suits you, may I ask you to check my answer as solved?